# Apache 2.4 "client denied by server configuration" caused by Require expr - even though the request succeeds

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Our apache error log is littered with messages saying `client denied by server configuration`, even though the htaccess configuration is working as intended.

Here is the relevant bit of the htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfExpr "req_novary('User-Agent') =~ /.*WHATEVER.*/" WHATEVER=1

<RequireAll>
    # Only allow access for these hosts
    Require expr "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /((host1|host2|host3)\.com)/"

    # Deny access if any of the rules in the RequireNone succeed!
    <RequireNone>
        # IIRC putting the two requires here is fine, it's an implicit OR.
         Require expr "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#.*RELEASE_NOTES\.txt#i"
        <RequireAll>
            # Block path unless it's one of the User Agents we want to allow
            Require expr "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#pathy/path#i"

            # This expr is what seems to trigger the error, even though the User Agent
            # matches and the server responds with a HTTP 200 code (and the request is successful).
            Require expr "!(reqenv('WHATEVER') == 1)"
        </RequireAll>
    </RequireNone>
</RequireAll>
```

If we test it using the correct user agent it works fine, we get an HTTP 200 and the response is valid. If we use a different UA it will give us a 403 Forbidden as expected. But on every successful request the error `client denied by server configuration` will be logged.

We had this same issue with a different `Require expr` statement, but we changed that one to a rewrite rule to resolve it (this previous issue was resulting in a log message for basically every resource access). We can do the same again here, but I'm curious why this may be resulting in the error.

Comment: What do you see in your "access" log?

Comment: On my host I see a transfer log, I believe this is equivalent to the normal access log. I have: 
> xx.xx.xx.xx - deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef [09/Feb/2023:02:45:43 +0000] "POST /pathy/path/webhook.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "WHATEVER/Webhooks".

At the same time in the error log I have: [Thu Feb 09 02:45:43 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 13303:tid 140382549309184] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:0] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /pathy/path/webhook.php

xx.xx.xx.xx - deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef [09/Feb/2023:02:45:43 +0000] "POST /pathy/path/webhook.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "WHATEVER/Webhooks"